# How to convert async generator to Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, async-iterator

I'm looking for a way, using build in function if that's possible, to convert async generator into array in JavaScript.

Example that work with generator:

```js
function* foo() { for (let x = 0; x < 10; ++x) yield x; }

console.log(Array.from(foo()));
console.log([...foo()]);
```

but the same don't work with async generator.

```js
async function* bar() { for (let x = 0; x < 10; ++x) yield x; }

console.log(Array.from(bar()));
[...bar()];
```

What is standard, and possible the shortest, way to convert Async generator/iterator into array like with normal generator/iterator?

Can I use standard functions (best if they are ES5 compatible like Array.from).

And to give the context I need this for my [Scheme based lisp interpreter called LIPS](https://lips.js.org/), I want to be able to call JavaScript function that is async generator and get the results.

this works in beta version of LIPS:

```lisp
(Array.from (foo))
;; ==> #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

but this don't:

```lisp
(Array.from (bar))
;; ==> #()
```

The same as in JavaScript.

And I'm not sure if I need to write a function (also not sure how to name it) that will convert async generator into Array, or maybe I need to write loop like `do` for that. Using iterator protocol I would be able to write code that would not require any new JavaScript.

But I'm not sure if something build in already exists for async generators lik `Array.from` for normal generators.

I know that you can use while with await for each result of `for await of` loop, but I'm looking for single function that would just create an array that I can use in LIPS without writing any extra function. Is something like this exists?

Comment: You can write your own prototype function, use npm lib or wait for support of async generators.